# Convert comma separated decimals from character to numeric

Tags: r, numeric

For my exam i have to build some scatter plots in r. I created a data frame with 4 variables. with this data frame i want to add regression lines to my scatter plots.

the name of my data frame is "alle".
variable names are: demo, tot, besch, usd

with this code i tried to line the regression line but got following result:

```
reg1<- lm(tot~demo, data=alle)
```

```
Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored

2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

here is the structure of "alle"

```
str(alle)
'data.frame':   11 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ demo : chr  "498.300.775" "500.297.033" "502.090.235" "503.170.618" ...
 $ tot  : Factor w/ 11 levels "4.846.423","4.871.049",..: 1 3 4 5 2 8 7 6 10 9 ...
 $ besch: Factor w/ 9 levels "68,4","68,6",..: 5 7 3 2 2 1 1 4 6 8 ...
 $ usd  : Factor w/ 44 levels "0,68434","0,72584",..: 26 30 29 23 28 22 24 25 15 14 ...
```

Tried to convert column "demo" to numeric with

```
alle$demo <- as.numeric(as.character(alle$demo))
```

it converted the column to numeric but now the rows are full with "NA"s.

I think that i all columns must be numeric. 
How  can I convert all 4 columns to numeric and finally plot the regression lines.

Data:

`> head(alle,6)
         demo       tot besch    usd
1 498.300.775 4.846.423  69,8 1,3705
2 500.297.033 4.891.934  70,3 1,4708
3 502.090.235 4.901.358  69,0 1,3948
4 503.170.618 4.906.313  68,6 1,3257
5 502.964.837 4.871.049  68,6 1,3920
6 504.047.964 5.010.371  68,4 1,2848`

thanks

Comment: Could you add your data with `dput(head(allele,10))`. Also what is a squatter plot?

Comment: Check my answer below(the second part) and see if it helps.

Comment: The data you share has NAs, is this the original data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
alle %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  mutate_at(c("besch","usd"),function(x) as.numeric(as.character(gsub(",",".",x)))) ->alle
    demo       tot besch    usd
1 498.300.775 4.846.423  69.8 1.3705
2 500.297.033 4.891.934  70.3 1.4708
3 502.090.235 4.901.358  69.0 1.3948
4 503.170.618 4.906.313  68.6 1.3257
5 502.964.837 4.871.049  68.6 1.3920
6 504.047.964 5.010.371  68.4 1.2848
```

Comment: my orginal data has no NAs. but after i tried the trick in first answer i get NAs in first two columns.

Comment: Please use your original data not data changed from an answer.

Comment: `apply(alle,2,function(x) as.numeric(as.character(gsub(",",".",x))))`

with this i get no changes on data grame

Comment: What output do you get and on what data?

Comment: on my orginal data (no NAs, every value with numbers) i got for this code `apply(alle,2,function(x) as.numeric(as.character(gsub(",",".",x))))` following output `Warning messages:
1: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: Please post your original data to the question. Simply print `head(allele,6)` and post that to the question.

Comment: have done it. have a look to my original post please.

Comment: @melooo check the edit. If you don't have `dplyr`, please `install.packages("dplyr")` first.

Comment: result seems good on console. but there are  no changes on my dataframe "alle". how can i  save this result to my data frame?

Comment: @melooI Just use `->` as usual and save as alle. You can accept this answer if it helps. :)

Comment: the first two columns are now charakter and the last two are numeric. dont know for now if all columns needs to be numeric to draw a regression line? 

now i have troubles to draw a regression line into my scatter plot. should i open a new post? or can i go forward here?

Comment: If you used this code, everything should be numeric. A regression plot does not always have to use numerics.

Comment: `str(alle)
'data.frame': 11 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ demo : chr  "498.300.775" "500.297.033" "502.090.235" "503.170.618" ...
 $ tot  : chr  "4.846.423" "4.891.934" "4.901.358" "4.906.313" ...
 $ besch: num  69.8 70.3 69 68.6 68.6 68.4 68.4 69.2 70.1 71.1 ...
 $ usd  : num  1.37 1.47 1.39 1.33 1.39 ...` 

not all are numeric :) but this code helped me alot

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it in two steps. First get rid of the dots, then replace the commas by decimal points and coerce to numeric.

```
alle[] <- lapply(alle, function(x) gsub("\\.", "", x))
alle[] <- lapply(alle, function(x) as.numeric(sub(",", ".", x)))
```

**Note:**

The above solution is broken in two for readability. The following does the same but it takes just one `lapply` loop and should therefore be faster if the dataset is big. If the dataset is small to medium, maybe the two steps solutions is preferable.

```
alle[] <- lapply(alle, function(x){
  as.numeric(sub(",", ".", gsub("\\.", "", x)))
})
```

Comment: tried it but got following error:
````
> alle[] <- lapply(alle, function(x) gsub("\\.", ", x"))
 Error in gsub("\\.", ", x") : argument "x" is missing, with no default > alle[] <- lapply(alle, function(x) as.numeric(sub(",", ".", x)))
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
````
the last two columns converted to numeric but the first two are now NAs.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Yes, thanks, corrected. I didn't test it, in the absence of data in the question.

Comment: @melooo See my previous comment. And the typo is now corrected. The error is probably gone.